# Size method not working on upgrading datanucleus

Tags: java, java-8, jdo, datanucleus

We were using version 3.1 of datanucleus for JDO with java 6 and recently we have upgraded it to v5 of datanucleus along with java 8. After upgrading we are facing issue in existing code when try to use count as size method.

```
Query tcQuery = pm.newQuery(TrialData.class);
tcQuery.addExtension("datanucleus.query.resultSizeMethod", "count");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Collection<TrialData> totalTrials = (Collection<TrialData>) tcQuery.execute();
int size = totalTrials.size();
```

It is throwing NucleusUserException exception.

```
datanucleus.query.resultSizeMethod of "COUNT" is only valid for use with JDOQL or JPQL currently
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: datanucleus.query.resultSizeMethod of "COUNT" is only valid for use with JDOQL or JPQL currently
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.getSizeUsingMethod(AbstractQueryResult.java:403)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.getSizeUsingMethod(ForwardQueryResult.java:521)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.size(AbstractQueryResult.java:256)
    at com.magna.juryconfirm.controllers.manager.Trials.trialSchedule(Trials.java:1040)
    at com.magna.juryconfirm.controllers.manager.Trials.trialSchedule(Trials.java:976)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.magna.juryconfirm.filters.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.magna.juryconfirm.filters.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.magna.juryconfirm.filters.AnonymizationFilter.doFilter(AnonymizationFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.magna.juryconfirm.filters.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.magna.juryconfirm.filters.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I've used COUNT size specification on DN 5.1 and have zero problems. Perhaps your log tells you more ...

Comment: Since you havent posted a LOG then this is assumed to be resolved, so why not add an answer about what your problem was